# Why does display === "none" not give result as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript function "display()". I what to make my nav display "none" on click, but is not working it just blinks

I want to make it work using only javascript. so i am not using queryselector

```js
function display() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-content");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="LiaWrapper clearfix">
    <h1 id="logo">logo</h1>
    <a href="" id="drop-down-icon" onclick="display()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
    <nav id="nav-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want to make my nav display none on click, but it just blinks on clicking

Comment: That's not the behaviour I see at all. You aren't cancelling navigation, so it may be doing what you want, then reloading the page because of `href=""`. Why are you using a link as a button anyway?

Comment: But your script is working all right here.

Comment: You need to add a "#" to your your href :  <a href="#" id="drop-down-icon" onclick="display()"> as when href is empty, it loads the same page again due to which it gives a blinking effect.

Comment: By the way, `querySelector` is JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are using onclick on `<a>` tag with href attribute as empty string.

Try removing href attribute from the a tag

`<a id="drop-down-icon" onclick="display()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></`i>

Check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3xc6qfme/

Comment: Far better to post code here as a runnable snippet, not elsewhere. Then you only have to post it once.

Comment: It works without this, too, although it does not stop the click event (which means it will go somewhere, or try).

Answer (score 0):

first remove the **href** attribute **anchor** tag is always used to redirect to certain url. best practice is to use

```
<input type="button" value="Click"/>
```

and then use your font awesome icons in place of value,
but if you want to use anchor tag then remove href attribute or as href use

**javascript:void(0)**

then try

Answer (score -1):

jquery: $("#id_name").css("display", "none");

javascript: document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";

Use this.

Comment: How is that different to the OP? Where did you explain the cause of the OP's problem, or how your code fixes it?